# First principles in Finance

Tags: risk-management, quants, terminology

Every so often I hear people referring to the term "first principles". It seems to me that this term does not necessarily have a universally accepted connotation in Finance. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle) is the general definition of the term:

> A first principle is a basic, foundational, self-evident proposition
>   or assumption that cannot be deduced from any other proposition or
>   assumption ...
>
> In a formal logical system, that is, a set of propositions that are
>   consistent with one another, it is possible that some of the
>   statements can be deduced from other statements ...

So what are  the major ***"self-evident propositions or assumptions that cannot be deduced from any other propositions"*** in Finance? Can one say that assumptions that make Black-Scholes option pricing model work are self-evident assumptions? How about Efficient Market Hypothesis?

If someone drops the term "first principles" nonchalantly during their formal or informal speech/presentation, do you ask for clarifications or just keep along with your own understanding of the term?

Please list first principles that you regularly use.

[QF SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=first%20principles) search results also give some interesting context.

Comment: Unlike in mathematics, there is no fixed list of first principles in Finance. But I would consider "no arbitrage" is the most important one, EMH comes next, then maybe Time Value of Money (discounting of future cash flows).

Comment: It is very difficult to apply your definition of "first principle" to finance, because it is not a theory by itself (in the sense of Model Theory), it is a collection of "frameworks" proposing mathematical formulations of problems practitioners are facing, and in for each framework, you have a list of mathematical tools that can help. Some theorems are derivated using standard maths to provide "off the shelf" tools for each framework.

Comment: @lehalle, maybe I am applying/defining the term in a wrong way, but certainly I have read and heard people refer to the first principles multiple times. Do you think they define and apply it differently? If so, I'd be interested to know in what ways.

Comment: The analogy that comes to my mind is the axioms of set theory in mathematics. However in economics/finance we cannot speak about universal axioms but axioms under a certain theory. For instance, expected utility theory and it's axioms. My intuition is that when someone refers to "first principles" he refers to a commonly accepted "truth" consistent with empirical findings and common sense. That is a good post, quite philosophical though

Comment: my point was that because we are not under the realm of Model Theory, there no clear definition of First Principles (and there cannot be), as a result people call FP what they want. I do not pay a lot of attention to “FP” in finance: your statement "self-evident propositions or assumptions that cannot be deduced from any other propositions"  simply does not apply to finance.

Comment: to be clear, in Model Theory terms you need Zermelo–Fraenkel + axiom of choice in finance (hence ZFC), because the Axiome of Choice is needed to define stochastic processes in dimension 2 or more. ZFC are the FP you are looking for, nothing more.

Comment: @alexbougias "expected utility theory" has no axioms, it has theorems and assumptions.

Comment: @lehalle  I mean the Von Neumann–Morgenstern formulation. The axioms of Completeness, Transitivity, Continuity and Independence. A quick google search has some relevant stuff.

Comment: I see what you mean @alexbougias, but from a Model Theory perspective, I think the elements of VNM are not "axioms" but assumptions. If I remember well axioms are need to conduct a reasoning, while assumptions are assertions used to obtain theorems. Anyway, I do not think that one can speak about FP in finance.

Comment: @lehalle I agree with that. This is my main argument when debating against economics and finance being a science. For instance, the VNM axioms may occasionally be violated so their universality is lost in contrast with maths. (Well, even in maths the axiomatic system may be limited due to it's incompleteness but that's another story)

Comment: @alexbougias I have a tendency to see the incompleteness of maths as a good point. Ok it somehow ended Hilbert's program (except for constructivists that ultimately allowed a theory of computed science to emerge), but it also show how maths are far more complex than a Turing machine ;{)}